# c# invoke c++ how to pass value with unit8

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a c# script I need to run in my C# application.

here is my c++ function,i hope can invoke it with c# in my c# application
the c++ prototype :

```
int ApplibUsbSimple_Login(UINT8 *buff)
```

i use c# invoke it:

```
[DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "login")]
public static extern int Login(????? buff)
```

i have seach the answer in google and stackoverflow just now,but i could not 
get the answer.
how should i replace the ????? with correct variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already noted, if the `UINT8` type used in your native function represents an 8-bit byte, you can map it to the `byte` type in C#.

Moreover, according to [this MSDN doc page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6cfh6e6(v=vs.110).aspx), if you take a look at the *C-Style Arrays* section, you can use this C# code for your byte array parameter:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] buff
```

In addition, there are a few questions for you: How can the native C-interface function know the *size* of the input array? Is this array 0-terminated? Is there another parameter in that function that specifies the size of the array in bytes? Is the size of the array fixed and specified as part of the function documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `byte[]`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/byte

Comment: how to pass parameter in c#?   i want pass the value :0x4f

Comment: @winter You want to pass only a single byte? I don't think you understand the function you call. Read its documentation. It accepts an array.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, C# doesn't have the exact type *uint8*, but the equivalent is *byte*.